# Dynamic MYSQL JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create one mysql query where I select all rows from a 'user' table and all rows from a 'partner' table where user.key == partner.key. However, there are situations that there is a user row with a certain key but there is no partner row for it.

How can I achieve to still show the results of 'user' when there is no match with 'partner.key'?

This how the query looks like at the moment:

```
SELECT 
    user.id, 
    user.key, 
    user.isSet,
    user.gender,
    user.firstname,
    user.lastname,

    partner.gender AS p_gender,
    partner.firstname AS p_firstname,
    partner.lastname AS p_lastname

    FROM user JOIN partner ON user.key = partner.forKey
```

Comment: Use left join instead of join. Left join gives all the data either they are null. in JOIN it gives you only perfect join data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do so using a LEFT JOIN :

```
SELECT 
    user.id, 
    user.key, 
    user.isSet,
    user.gender,
    user.firstname,
    user.lastname,
    user.dob,
    user.persnumb,
    user.expdate,
    user.phone,
    user.emergency,
    user.medical,
    user.diet,
    user.bodysize,
    user.headsize,
    user.misc,
    user.takesPartner, 

    partner.gender AS p_gender,
    partner.firstname AS p_firstname,
    partner.lastname AS p_lastname,
    partner.dob AS p_dob,
    partner.persnumb AS p_persnumb,
    partner.expdate AS p_expdate,
    partner.phone AS p_phone,
    partner.emergency AS p_emergency,
    partner.medical AS p_medical,
    partner.diet AS p_diet,
    partner.bodysize AS p_bodysize,
    partner.headsize AS p_headsize,
    partner.misc AS p_misc

    FROM user LEFT JOIN partner ON user.key = partner.forKey
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * FROM user LEFT JOIN partner ON user.key = partner.forKey

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.key, 
    u.isSet,
    u.gender,
    u.firstname,
    u.lastname,

```
p.gender AS p_gender,
p.firstname AS p_firstname,
p.lastname AS p_lastname

FROM user u LEFT JOIN partner p ON u.key = p.forKey;
```